# ShareKit : Facebook connection issue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, sharekit

getshrekit.com : Yesterday I was facing problem in Facebook. I was register App on Facebook and that keys are incorporated in ShareKit when I was click the Facebook button I was getting error Screen shot attached.

Please provide your feedback.![image]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use ShareKit, you need to first check updated version of it. You can follow this link and i hope it will certainly help you. http://getsharekit.com/docs/